# Some SVG and Defs For Text Animations

Tags: svg

I have a template in which all section heads are given in SVG and defs etc. But no Actual Text. That defs and SVG tags make Text animated. 
I want to change the Text. How i should do.

My Code is here.. This code Animates word "WORK" but there is not WORK written in codes. This makes me confused..

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="223.9" height="45.4" viewBox="0 0 223.9 45.4" enable-background="new 0 0 223.9 45.4" xml:space="preserve">
                <defs>
                    <clipPath id="work-clip">
                        <path d="M22.3 39.5h-4.5L6.6 5.9h6.5l7 21 7.4-21h4.6l7.4 21 7-21H53L41.8 39.5h-4.6l-7.5-21.3-7.4 21.3zM77.9 35c-3.3-3.3-4.9-7.4-4.9-12.3C73 13 80.3 5.4 90.5 5.4S108 13 108 22.7 100.7 40 90.5 40c-5.2 0-9.4-1.7-12.6-5zm4.7-20.5c-2.1 2.2-3.2 4.9-3.2 8.2 0 6.4 4.8 11.5 11 11.5s11-5.1 11-11.5-4.8-11.5-11-11.5c-3.1 0-5.7 1.1-7.8 3.3zM139 24.6v14.9h-6.5V5.9h12.2c3.1 0 5.5.8 7.3 2.5 2 1.9 3 4.2 3 6.9s-1 5-3 6.9c-1 .9-2.1 1.5-3.4 2l12.6 15.4h-8l-12-14.9H139zm0-13v7.2h5.4c3.1 0 4.2-1.6 4.2-3.5 0-2.1-1.1-3.7-4.2-3.7H139zM190.4 23v16.5H184V5.9h6.5v13.5l12.7-13.5h8.6L197 21.3l16.5 18.2h-8.3L190.4 23z"/>
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>
                <g class="letters" clip-path="url(#work-clip)" stroke="#1D1D1F" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-miterlimit="10">
                    <g class="letter-w">
                        <polyline class="outline-1" points="53,5.9 41.8,39.5 37.3,39.5 29.8,18.2 22.3,39.5 17.8,39.5 6.6,5.9"/>
                        <polyline class="fill-2" points="25.7,20.5 29.8,8.8 39.5,36.6 50.2,4.4"/>
                        <polyline class="fill-1" points="9.4,4.4 20.1,36.6 25.7,20.5"/>
                        <polyline class="outline-2" points="13.2,5.9 20.1,26.8 27.5,5.9 32.1,5.9 39.5,26.8 46.4,5.9"/>
                    </g>
                    <g class="letter-o">
                        <path class="outline-1" d="M108,22.7c0,9.7-7.3,17.3-17.5,17.3c-5.1,0-9.3-1.7-12.6-5s-4.9-7.4-4.9-12.3c0-9.7,7.3-17.3,17.5-17.3S108,13,108,22.7"/>
                        <path class="outline-2" d="M79.4,22.7c0,6.4,4.8,11.5,11,11.5s11-5.1,11-11.5s-4.8-11.5-11-11.5c-3.1,0-5.8,1.1-7.9,3.4S79.4,19.5,79.4,22.7"/>
                        <path class="fill" d="M99.6,11.2c-2.4-2.1-5.6-3.4-9.2-3.4c-4.1,0-7.5,1.5-10.2,4.3c-2.7,2.9-4.1,6.4-4.1,10.5c0,8.3,6.2,14.9,14.3,14.9s14.3-6.6,14.3-14.9C104.7,18,102.8,13.9,99.6,11.2"/>
                    </g>
                    <g class="letter-r">
                        <path class="outline-1" d="M132.6,5.9h12.2c3.1,0,5.5,0.8,7.3,2.5c2,1.9,3,4.2,3,6.9"/>
                        <line class="outline-2" x1="132.6" y1="39.5" x2="132.6" y2="5.9"/>
                        <path class="outline-3" d="M155.1,15.2c0,2.7-1,5-3,6.9c-1,0.9-2.1,1.5-3.4,2l12.6,15.4"/>
                        <path class="outline-4" d="M139,15.2v3.6h5.4c3.1,0,4.2-1.6,4.2-3.5"/>
                        <path class="outline-5" d="M148.7,15.3c0-2.1-1.1-3.7-4.2-3.7H139v3.6"/>
                        <line class="fill-1" x1="135.8" y1="40" x2="135.8" y2="6.3"/>
                        <path class="fill-2" d="M135.2,21.7h9.3c5.4,0,7.3-2.8,7.3-6.3c0-3.7-2-6.6-7.3-6.6h-9.3"/>
                        <line class="fill-3" x1="159.7" y1="42.4" x2="143" y2="21.7"/>
                    </g>
                    <g class="letter-k">
                        <line class="outline-1" x1="184" y1="39.5" x2="184" y2="5.9"/>
                        <polyline class="outline-2" points="196.9,21.2 213.5,39.5 205.2,39.5"/>
                        <polyline class="outline-3" points="190.4,19.3 203.2,5.9 211.7,5.9"/>
                        <line class="fill-1" x1="187.3" y1="39.5" x2="187.3" y2="5.9"/>
                        <line class="fill-2" x1="210.6" y1="3" x2="190.9" y2="23.5"/>
                        <line class="fill-3" x1="210.6" y1="41.4" x2="190.7" y2="19"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
```

Please Help me to change the Text...

Answer (score 1):

Your text has been converted to paths.  Note the four groups with class `letter-w`, `letter-o`, `letter-r`, `letter-k`.  To change the text, you have to remove those groups and replace with a `<text>` element.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="223.9" height="45.4" viewBox="0 0 223.9 45.4" enable-background="new 0 0 223.9 45.4" xml:space="preserve">
                <defs>
                    <clipPath id="work-clip">
                        <path d="M22.3 39.5h-4.5L6.6 5.9h6.5l7 21 7.4-21h4.6l7.4 21 7-21H53L41.8 39.5h-4.6l-7.5-21.3-7.4 21.3zM77.9 35c-3.3-3.3-4.9-7.4-4.9-12.3C73 13 80.3 5.4 90.5 5.4S108 13 108 22.7 100.7 40 90.5 40c-5.2 0-9.4-1.7-12.6-5zm4.7-20.5c-2.1 2.2-3.2 4.9-3.2 8.2 0 6.4 4.8 11.5 11 11.5s11-5.1 11-11.5-4.8-11.5-11-11.5c-3.1 0-5.7 1.1-7.8 3.3zM139 24.6v14.9h-6.5V5.9h12.2c3.1 0 5.5.8 7.3 2.5 2 1.9 3 4.2 3 6.9s-1 5-3 6.9c-1 .9-2.1 1.5-3.4 2l12.6 15.4h-8l-12-14.9H139zm0-13v7.2h5.4c3.1 0 4.2-1.6 4.2-3.5 0-2.1-1.1-3.7-4.2-3.7H139zM190.4 23v16.5H184V5.9h6.5v13.5l12.7-13.5h8.6L197 21.3l16.5 18.2h-8.3L190.4 23z"/>
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>
                <g class="letters" stroke="#1D1D1F" fill="none" stroke="#010101" stroke-miterlimit="10">
                    <text x="6" y="40" font-size="50">W O R K</text>
                </g>
</svg>
```

However now you have the issue of whether the machine rendering the SVG has the right font you need or not. Which is why it will have been converted to paths originally.

Also, I don't know whether your animation will still work, because you haven't included it.

If your animation doesn't work, you will probably have to load the SVG file into an SVG editor on a machine that has the right font. Then replace the text as needed and finally convert to paths again.

Comment: But I have no svg file. Everything is in these codes only. No SVG files. And I am unable to understand how to load svg file in editor. Can you please tell me which editor i should use

Comment: Save the part of the file from `<svg>` to </svg>` and load into almost any vector editor. Inkscape is a free one.

Comment: No. There is no way to convert paths to text.